# prefect task status shows Retrying while it srarted Running

Tags: scheduled-tasks, orchestration, prefect

I am using Prefect for orchestration and have put re-try for tasks.

I manually killed one of the tasks to check if retry is working. After that I saw it started retry based on condition and job got restarted but in the UI task it is showing retrying still.

Below are the Output details from UI and CMD line output:

```
task-0
Retrying
9m 41s
2023/03/25 08:47:11 AM


08:56:52.269 | INFO    | Task run 'task-0' - Received non-final state 'AwaitingRetry' when proposing final state 'Failed' and will attempt to run again...
```

No further info is printed while task re-started and status in UI is showing still Retrying`.

I tried retry and was expecting status to turn to running.

Comment: what version? what infrastructure are you using?

Comment: i am using 'prefect2.0', infra-structure - windows server

Comment: also more details about the task run is that i am calling stored_procedure using cursor execute

Answer (score 0):

Did refreshing the browser work? I suggest upgrading Prefect to the latest version. Does the issue persist?

Comment: For an input as tentative and "maybe" as this, please use your commenting privilege. Or [edit] to rephrase more assertively and maybe more according to [answer].